# Extract text from HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I would like to extract text from HTML with pure Javascript (this is for a Chrome extension).

Specifically, I would like to be able to find text on a page and extract text after it.

Even more specifically, on a page like

https://picasaweb.google.com/kevin.smilak/BestOfAmericaSGrandCircle#4974033581081755666

I would like to find text "Latitude" and extract the value that goes after it. HTML there is not in a very structured form.

What is an elegant solution to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no elegant solution in my opinion because as you said HTML is not structured and the words "Latitude" and "Longitude" depends on page localization.
Best I can think of is relying on the cardinal points, which might not change...

```
var data = document.getElementById("lhid_tray").innerHTML;
var lat = data.match(/((\d)*\.(\d)*)°(\s*)(N|S)/)[1];
var lon = data.match(/((\d)*\.(\d)*)°(\s*)(E|W)/)[1];
```

Comment: I really don't think you can rely on `° W` and `° N` not changing, but you can easily change `N` to `N|S` and `W` to `E|W` in the regexes.

Comment: I was convinced that lat & lon were always expressed in terms of N, W. I'll edit the regex.

Comment: lat & lon should have minus signs if element `[3]` of the regexp is `S` and `W` correspondingly, but these are further details that could be implemented with two extra lines of code...

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
var str = document.getElementsByClassName("gphoto-exifbox-exif-field")[4].innerHTML;
var latPos = str.indexOf('Latitude')
lat = str.substring(str.indexOf('<em>',latPos)+4,str.indexOf('</em>',latPos))
```

Answer (score 1):

The text you're interested in is found inside of a `div` with class `gphoto-exifbox-exif-field`. Since this is for a Chrome extension, we have `document.querySelectorAll` which makes selecting that element easy:

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div.gphoto-exifbox-exif-field')[4],
    text = div.innerText;

/* text looks like:
"Filename: img_3474.jpg
Camera: Canon
Model: Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL
ISO: 800
Exposure: 1/60 sec
Aperture: 5.0
Focal Length: 18mm
Flash Used: No
Latitude: 36.872068° N
Longitude: 111.387291° W"
*/
```

It's easy to get what you want now:

```
var lng = text.split('Longitude:')[1].trim(); // "111.387291° W"
```

I used `trim()` instead of `split('Longitude: ')` since that's not actually a space character in the `innerText` (URL-encoded, it's `%C2%A0` ...no time to figure out what that maps to, sorry).

Comment: It does. Firefox is the outlier here (use `textContent` instead). http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04

Answer (score 0):

I would query the DOM and just collect the image information into an object, so you can reference any property you want.

E.g.

```
function getImageData() {
    var props = {};
    Array.prototype.forEach.apply(
        document.querySelectorAll('.gphoto-exifbox-exif-field > em'),
        [function (prop) {
            props[prop.previousSibling.nodeValue.replace(/[\s:]+/g, '')] = prop.textContent;
        }]
    );
    return props;
}

var data = getImageData();
console.log(data.Latitude); // 36.872068° N
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if a more general answer is required for other sites then you can try something like:

```
var text = document.body.innerHTML;
text = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");  //strip out all HTML tags
var latArray = text.match(/Latitude:?\s*[^0-9]*[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\s*°\s*[NS]/gim);
//search for and return an array of all found results for:
//"latitude", one or 0 ":", white space, A number, white space, 1 or 0 "°", white space, N or S
//(ignores case)(ignores multi-line)(global)
```

For that example an array of 1 element containing "Latitude: 36.872068° N" is returned (which should be easy to parse).

Comment: Note: I am not a regex expert by any means, that example should work for almost anything but I am sure their are more complete and elegant solutions.