# Get all text as a string from page

Tags: javascript, html, document, innertext

I want to get all the text from an html page into a string a print it on the console. So far I have this piece of code that works only partially because document.body.innerText returns the text together with line brakes which I certainly dont want. I want all my text to appear in 1 line

```
<html>
    <head>
        <h1>wtf</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>dddiiiv</div>
        <a>aaaaa</a>
        <p>ppp</p>
        <div>div</div>
        <div id="impar"></div>
        <div id="par"></div>
        <div id="all"></div>
        <script>
            var elems = document.body.innerText;
            var odd = "";
            var even = "";
            var all = "";
            for (k in elems){
                all = all + elems[k];
                if (k % 2 === 0) {
                    even = even + elems[k]
                } else {
                    odd = odd + elems[k]
                }
            }


            console.log(all);
            console.log(odd);
            console.log(even);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea of a get around for the innerText's brakes?

Comment: Remove newlines? `str.replace(/\n/g, "");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract text from HTML with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090395/extract-text-from-html-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used .trim() and codepen URL for reference -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jrPpeK

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <h1>wtf</h1>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>dddiiiv</div>
            <a>aaaaa</a>
            <p>ppp</p>
            <div>div</div>
            <div id="impar"></div>
            <div id="par"></div>
            <div id="all"></div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript

```
    var elems = document.body.innerText;
                var odd = "";
                var even = "";
                var all = "";
                for (k in elems){
                    all = all + elems[k];
                    if (k % 2 === 0) {
                        even = (even + elems[k]).trim();
                    } else {
                        odd = (odd + elems[k]).trim();
                    }
                }


                console.log(all);
                console.log(odd);
                console.log(even);
```

Hope this is helpful